# How to Take custom inputs

Tags: java

The first line contain two separated integer N and M.
Where N stands for Number of Buildings and M stands for Roads.

Next follows M line, each lines consists of 4 integers I J K L representing Floor of Building, Windows in building,Time taken to climb the building, Time taken to cross road.

I have been able to taken the first input as follows:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter N and M");
String NandM = sc.nextLine();
String [] NandMAsArray = NandM.split(" ");
int N = Integer.parseInt(NandMAsArray[0]);
int M = Integer.parseInt(NandMAsArray[1]);
```

I am struck while taking input for second part , which will consist of a loop of M time and taking **4** inputs each time, `I J K L` respectively.

How do i do this??

input and output for second part should be like this:

**Input:**

```
Road:0
12 34 44 56

Road:1
22 76 89 90
```

https://i.postimg.cc/28fQ3dVR/Screenshot-20190807-121551-Chrome.jpg

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Please read up on Java naming conventions, and capitalize your variable names `likeThisCasing` _not_ `LikeThis`.  Variables start with a lower case letter, _class_ names start with a capital letter like you used.  It also helps to use names that mean something, like `roads` and `buildings` to make the code readable.

Comment: For each road `M` you are gonna ask user 4 inputs `I(floors) J(windows) K(climbingTime) L(crossingTime)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am struck while taking input for second part , which will consist of a loop of M time and taking 4 inputs each time, I J K L respectively

Based on your requirement I'd suggest you create a class rather than using primitive types. This will be easier than making a 2D array and you can do more with data.

Since I don't exactly know the problem I am gonna assume that (Floor of Building, Windows in building,Time taken to climb the building, Time taken to cross road) all are properties of road. If not then you can same thing to buildings and move the attributes from road to building

> Road Class

```
public class Road {

    private int floorsOfBuilding;
    private int windowsInBuilding;
    private int climbTime;
    private int crossingTime;

    // Constructor
    public Road(int floorsOfBuilding, int windowsInBuilding, int climbTime, int crossingTime) {
        this.floorsOfBuilding = floorsOfBuilding;
        this.windowsInBuilding = windowsInBuilding;
        this.climbTime = climbTime;
        this.crossingTime = crossingTime;
        // You can do simple calculations here but for more complex it is better
        // to create a method to maintain readability
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + floorsOfBuilding + " " + windowsInBuilding + "  " + climbTime + "  " + crossingTime;
    }
}
```

> Main Class

```
int roadsCount = Integer.parseInt(buildingsAndRoadsArray[1]);
Road[] roadsArray = new Road[roadsCount];
for (int i = 0; i < roadsArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Road:" + i);
    System.out.print("Enter I J K L: ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    String[] inputSplit = input.split(" ");
    Road road = new Road(Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[0]), Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[1]),
            Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[2]), Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[3]));
    roadsArray[i] = road;
}
scan.close();
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < roadsArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Road: " + i + roadsArray[i] + "\n");
}
```

> Output

```
Enter Number of Buildings and Roads: 1 2
// Input
Road:0
Enter I J K L: 12 13 14 15

Road:1
Enter I J K L: 49 59 69 79
// Output
Road: 0
12 13  14  15

Road: 1
49 59  69  79
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking, i want each round input to be in same line.

Comment: I want like this https://i.postimg.cc/28fQ3dVR/Screenshot-20190807-121551-Chrome.jpg

Comment: @WELoveCode That is super easy. You just need to change toString() method in Road Class.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    int I = sc.nextInt();
    int J = sc.nextInt();
    int K = sc.nextInt():
    int L = sc.nextInt();

    // your code here
}
```

Since the input is constant, you can just take in the numbers directly.